# Rails: ActiveRecord Query with Associations and OR Operator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-associations, or-operator

I can't seem to find a "Rails-Way" for the following query:

Here are my model definitions:

```
class Backend::Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :backend_order_filter, :class_name => 'Backend::OrderFilter', :dependent => :destroy

class Backend::OrderFilter < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :backend_order, :class_name => 'Backend::Order', :foreign_key => 'order_id'
```

Here is my raw working sql-query:

```
Backend::Order.find_by_sql(
    "SELECT `backend_orders`.*,`backend_order_filters`.*,`backend_customers`.*
      FROM `backend_orders`
      LEFT JOIN `backend_order_filters` ON (`backend_orders`.`id` = `backend_order_filters`.`order_id`)
      WHERE
          (`backend_orders`.`order_status` IN ('OK', 'AO') OR `backend_orders`.`order_status` IS NULL) AND
          (`backend_order_filters`.`financing` = 1 OR (`backend_orders`.`price` - `backend_orders`.`balance`) <= 0)AND
          `backend_orders`.`delivery_number` IN ('21','22') AND (`backend_order_filters`.`places_of_delivery` = 1)"
)
```

I've tried to do it with Arel-tables because of the OR Operator between "Backend::Order" and "Backend::OrderFilter", but I can't find a solution. I also searched on Stack Overflow for a similar problem but unfortunately I was out of luck. All the answers regarding Arel-tables consider only one main model without an association.
Thank you for any help.